# C# Event listener from worker service

Tags: c#, events

I have invoked event from endpoint and i need listen from worker service if event is invoked run  some method

```
public class WorkerService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<WorkerService> _logger;
    private readonly IEventService _eventService;

    public WorkerService(ILogger<WorkerService> logger, IEventService eventService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _eventService = eventService;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _eventService.RegEvent += Log;
         await Task.Delay(2000);
        _eventService.RegEvent -= Log;

    }

    private void Log(string message)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("dssd");
    }
}

public interface IEventService
{
    public delegate void RegistrationEvent(string message);

    public event RegistrationEvent RegEvent;
    public void InvokeEvent();

}

public class EventService : IEventService
{
    private readonly ILogger<EventService> _logger;

    public event IEventService.RegistrationEvent RegEvent;

    public EventService(ILogger<EventService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void InvokeEvent()
    {
        RegEvent?.Invoke("Test message");
        _logger.LogInformation($"From {nameof(EventService)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share error details you are getting to be more specific

Comment: Unrelated: _"logger.LogInformation($"From {nameof(EventService)}");"_ - the source of the log comes with the category and microsoft recommends **not** to use string interpolation in log message templates.

Comment: On topic: It's pretty unclear what the question is but it _is_ clear that this only works for 2 seconds ... I guess that's not what is intended, right? You may be in need of a different service type that providdes you with a start and stop hook, so you can just register the event handler on start and deregister again on stop.

Comment: I does not getting sent message from Event Service
Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Yes you are: _" ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken)  

This method is called when the IHostedService starts. **The implementation should return a task that represents the lifetime of the long running operation(s) being performed**."_ - that means that the method shall only return, when the service shuts down. You run it for 2 seconds and that's it.

Comment: You may want to consider [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) instead.

Comment: while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _eventService.RegEvent += Log;

                await Task.Delay(2000, stoppingToken);
            }
I had this example

Comment: That example (from your comment above) - in contrast to the code in the question -  will keep the method "running" ( keep the Task from completing ) as long as it isn't signaled by the runtime. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Maybe I initially wrote the logic incorrectly, the point is that the user is successfully registered, send an event and inform the services about it

Comment: i have fixed this with Hosted Service and change ServiceCollection registration type to singleton